# Jquery Validation in MVC .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to add jquery validation on MVC form. I have given the form id as

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "Technologyform" }))
```

and the input field

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 ", @id = "MyName" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

My Jquery script is like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MyName').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: 'The title field is required.'
        }
    });
    $(function() {
        $( "#Technologyform" ).validate({
            rules: {
                Name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 20,
                }
            },
            messages: {
                Name: {
                    required: "Dude, enter a name",
                    minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
                    maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Its not working. what to do

Comment: You'll need to tell us what you mean when you say it's "not working".  What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?  Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: You do not even have a form control with `id="MyName"` (but you do have one with `id="Name"`. But why are you doing this manually instead of using jquery.validate.unbtrusive.js?

Comment: and `id` inside `Html helper` doesn't require `@` prefixed.. as in `@id`

Answer (score 0):

you are following wrong way. you are already using Model for create your own form , so its better to using  jquery.validate.unbtrusive , all you do is update your model.

```
   public class Whatever
   {
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dude, enter a name")]
      [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Dude are you joking me you cannot enter that much character.. ")]        
      [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Not enough character enter moree..")]
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

after this just remove all your javascript code. and remember adding jquery.validate.unbtrusive.js as link

Answer (score 0):

- You need to also add reference of **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js**.
- Enable or disable the client side validations in MVC by doing simple
  configuration / code changes. in Web.Config.
  `<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>`

You can also refer give link for more details 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/